# How do I specify that an operation is returning a template with a template parameter bound to something with * multiplicity?

Tags: visual-studio-2013, uml, class-diagram

In UML, I want an operation of the form:

```
+operation(param: String): Binding
```

where I want Binding to be a bound type as:

```
Template<TParam -> ISingle[*]>
```

and Template is defined as:

```
Template<TParam:Interface>
```

Comment: 1. You mean, specify *in UML*? You have omitted that info. 2. You can do a diagram up to task set in words or/and more common diagrams. From the other side, you can do diagram from a piece of code. But you can't put some separate lines of pseudocode and think that you have set the task. I have tried to do the diagram, but it is impossible, for I do not understand what you want.

Comment: @Gangus Yes, I'm trying to represent the concept in UML. Everything I have above is standard UML syntax, except the second line which apparently isn't possible using that syntax. I was looking for an alternative syntax that would work.